# Should I reject edits which fix the typo in the question and invalidate the answer?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

A question came up which asked why this statement (in R):

```
 n <- 1000 x <- seq(1,n) sum(x)
```

Returned an error

> Error: object 'x' not found

Here, the statement `n <- 1000` and `x <- seq(1,n) sum(x)` should be on newlines or separated by semi colons, hence the error. In truth, it's a typo so should be closed as such anyway.

Someone answered the question saying they should do this and split the code across lines.

Someone else then proposed an edit to the question to 'fix the formatting', so that the question is now like this:

```
n <- 1000
x <- seq(1,n)
sum(x)

# Error: object 'x' not found
```

In my view, this just totally invalidates the whole premise of the question and makes the answer redundant. The place to do this would be in an answer, not an edit to the question.

Aside from the fact that it's a poor question and should be closed anyway, should edits which correct the original problem be rejected?

Comment: Yes. Edits aren't supposed to "fix" code in questions, *certainly* not when that mistake is germane to the question itself.

Comment: Thanks, I was pretty sure that was the case but wanted to check before rolling back the edit.

Comment: Yup. Actually, if the edit got incorrectly approved, and no edits have been made after it, then a moderator can override that approval. You can raise a moderator flag on the post to request this, pointing us to the edit. That way, we can not only override the approval of the edit, but we can also consider whether we need to reach out to the users who approved the invalid edit to teach them how to make better reviews in the future.

Comment: I must admit, when I *do* decide to review suggested edits, it's one of the reasons I skip any suggestions which reformat the code (significantly) in a language I don't know, as I can't make an informed decision on whether it will effect the code itself.